# Unable to connect to MS Access Database

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, jdbc-odbc

This is my code:

```
public class ConnectDB {
Connection conn;
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
public String ID;
public ConnectDB()
{
try
     {
        Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println ("Driver successfully loaded");
     }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
           System.out.println ("Unable to load database driver");
        }

  //connect to the database
     try
     {
    String filename = "PATPhase2DB.mdb";
    String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ=";
    database += filename.trim () + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true}";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection (database,"","");
    System.out.println ("Connection to database successfully established");

     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.out.println ("Unable to connect to the database");
     }
}
```

The Messages Are:
Driver successfully loaded
Unable to connect to the database
java.lang.NullPointerException

This has worked on a different computer than mine, connecting to the database through exactly the same code. I am also running Windows 8.

Comment: you're capturing an exception - what information does that give?

Comment: Which Exception?
and the nullointerexcpetion is pointing to the line
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection (database,"","");

Comment: Exception e, can you post that on the bottom of your question

Comment: I'm new to java and when we received the coding in class, that's how we got it. The program works on other computers. And i have a 32 bit access.

Comment: Now it's giving this message Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x1d38 Thread 0x13dc DBC 0x1c317114

Answer (score 3):

This is very common error.
Reason is that `some other application is using your database` (most commonly you have opened database in Microsoft Access).
Close it and enjoy.
EDIT:
This answer is for error user mentioned in comment(**unable to open registry key 'temporary (volatile)**)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
System.out.println ("Unable to connect to the database");
System.out.println ("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
```

then you can get a deeper glimpse of what went wrong

Comment: Now it's giving this message
Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0x1d38 Thread 0x13dc DBC 0x1c317114

Comment: hmm, seems like the computer you're running it on now down't have the right driver, have a look here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/can-anyone-please-help-re-access-connection-errors/68a6f9eb-ef3a-4291-9ebf-5ce212665283

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
I didn't seem to be able to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your `Driver=` name is missing a space. You've defined it as...

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};
```

...but it should be...

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
```

You also have a stray `}` at the end of your connection string, but that doesn't seem to hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to mention the entire path of your access database file and the url between extensions (`.mdb, *.accdb`) space is mandatory e.g.:

```
String database="C:/Users/GIRI/Desktop/fdsfkdsfj/abc.accdb";
String url="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + database + ";DriverID=22;READONLY=true";
```